# Mobile Firemonkey Application localization

Tags: android, delphi, localization, firemonkey

I am trying to build a multilanguage Firemonkey Mobile application for Android using Delphi XE5 update1.

I tried using the TLang component but it seems to be completely broken. Is there another way to code my way to store the multilang strings and bring them up when i have selected a language from my application menu?

Comment: On 2013 Sisulizer didn't support Firemonkey Mobile Apps yet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For simple projects TLang works fine, but you're right: The included "Language Designer" (doubleclick on the TLang component) is not much fun and seems to have many issues.
I wrote a tool to handle this issues and enable easy import of extern translated CSV files.
The progress then:

1. Use TLang for parsing your sources and resources for strings.
2. Export them to a text file.
3. In a extern spreadsheet or translation tool you do your translations.
4. Use the TLang converter tool to create a LNG file out of the CSV file.
5. Import the LNG File into the TLang component.

See [TLang converter](http://1st.bitbumper.de/delphi-fmx-tlang-component-data-creation/) for more informations.

For large projects you may also check out some commercial products for translating/localization of Delphi FMX projects like: 
http://www.sisulizer.de
http://www.tsilang.com
http://www.regulace.org

Comment: TLang does not translate the Dialog texts ( Yes, No, Cancel etc). To change those, you have to change FMX.Dialogs.pas

Answer (score 1):

You can hook `CustomTranslateProc: TCustomTranslateProc` from FMX.Types to localise for example dialog buttons see http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/FMX.Types.CustomTranslateProc

Answer (score 0):

You can use GnuGetText, it works fine with FireMonkey. You just have to call TranslateComponents in each form's constructor.

Here is a Delphi implementation for GnuGetText: http://dxgettext.po.dk/

Regarding string extraction: the xfm files are not recognized out of the box. You have to rename (or copy) them temporarly to dfm and then run the extraction tool.

Comment: I installed the GnuGetText but are you sure it works with FireMonkey? I used the folder right click 'Extract translations to template' and it created a .po file that only included my datasnap server files. It exluded all my firemonkey mobile forms... plus i am having a bit of difficulty to find instructions on how to use it... thanks a lot for the answer though, i will continue searching on how it's used and i will come back with more.

Comment: Did you use dxgettext? I edited my answer to include the link. We use this approach successfully with http://snaptip.com - but I must admit I only read "firemonkey" and not "mobile". I'm not sure if dxgettext can be compiled with the mobile compiler, but when it does it should work.